# TYPO3 - Change Layout according to amount of entrys

Tags: foreach, conditional-statements, fluid, typo3-9.x

I want to change my Page Layout according to how many files are existing.

I developed the following code:

```
                        <f:for each="{files}" as="file">
                          <div class="ce-textpic-file-download-wrapper">
                            <a href="/fileadmin/{file.identifier}" target="_blank">
                                <div class="filesize">({file.originalFile})</div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                      </f:for>
```

Now there are different cases:

- No files given -> empty div
- 1 File given -> Just show the one File
- 2 Files given -> Add Row with two columns, each column is col-6 and contains the file
- 3 Files given -> row(col-6, col-6), row(col-6)
- 4 Files given -> 2 rows, each with 2 col-6
- 5 or more files -> Just show the first 4 Files (as    described in "4
  files given")

How can i accomplish something like this. 
I am using Typo3-9.5.5 btw

Is this a possible solution?

```
<f:switch expression="{files -> f.count()}">
  <f:case value="0">EMPTY</f:case>
  <f:case value="1">ONE</f:case>
  <f:case value="2">TWO</f:case>
  <f:case value="3">THREE FILES</f:case>
  <f:case value="4">FOUR</f:case>
  <f:defaultCase>MORE THAN FOUR</f:defaultCase>
</f:switch>
```

How can i address for exmaple the third element in {files} does it work like this: {files}[2]?

EDIT:
I solved it like this (There was no need for more than one row class):

```
  <f:if condition="{files}">
                        <f:if condition="{files->f:count()} == 1">
                            <f:then>
                                <div class="row download-row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="ce-textpic-file-download-wrapper ">
                                            <a href="/fileadmin/{files.0.identifier}" target="_blank">
                                                <div class="fileinfo">
                                                    {files.0.originalFile.properties.name}<br>
                                                    ({files.0.originalFile.properties.size})
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6"></div>
                                </div>
                            </f:then>
                            <f:else>
                                <div class="row">
                                <f:for each="{files}" as="file" iteration="iterator">
                                    <f:if condition="{iterator.index} < 4">
                                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                                            <div class="ce-textpic-file-download-wrapper">
                                                <a href="/fileadmin/{files.iterator.identifier}" target="_blank">
                                                    <div class="fileinfo test">
                                                        {file.originalFile.properties.name}<br>
                                                        ({file.originalFile.properties.size}
                                                    </div>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </f:if>
                                </f:for>
                            </f:else>
                        </f:if>
                    </f:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your variety of cases you might use different `f:for` viewhelper or change just the rendering inside of one single `f:for`viewhelper for all.
But you also should make use of the information an `iterator` will give you inside the `f:for` viewhelper.
You also might use a `f:cycle` viewhelper, so you do not need to caclulate `modulo`.

```xml
Number of files: {files->f:count()}<br />
<f:for each="{files}" as="file" iteration="iterator">
    <f:cycle values="{0: 'odd', 1: 'even'}" as="cycler"> 
        <f:debug title="inside the loop">{file:file, iterator:iterator, cycler:cycler}</f:debug>
    </f:cycle>
</f:for>
```

EDIT:

---

regarding your cases I think you must consider two variants:

```xml
   <f:if condition="{files}">
      <f:if condition="{files->f:count()} == 1">
         <f:then>
            <f:render section="item" arguments="{file:file}" />
         </f:then>
         <f:else>
            <f:for each="{files}" as="file" iteration="iterator">
               <f:if condition="{iterator.index} < 4">
                  <f:if condition="iterator.isOdd"><div class="row"></f:if>
                     <div class="col-6">
                        <f:render section="item" arguments="{file:file}" />
                     </div>
                  <f:if condition="iterator.isEven"></div></f:if>
               </f:if>
            </f:for>
            <f:if condition="{files->f:count()} == 3"></div></f:if>
        </f:else>
      </f:if>
   </f:if>

<f:section name="item">
<div class="ce-textpic-file-download-wrapper">
    <a href="/fileadmin/{file.identifier}" target="_blank">
        <div class="filesize">({file.originalFile})</div>
    </a>
</div>
</f:section>
```

EDIT2:

---

```xml
<f:section name="item">
<div class="ce-textpic-file-download-wrapper">
    <f:link.typolink parameter="{file.publicUrl}" target="_blank">
        {file.identifier} 
        <span class="filesize"> ({file.size->f:format.bytes()})</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

just remember: aside of the properties visible in a `<f:debug title="file">{file}</f:debug>` you have a lot of other properies, given by the getters you could see in the [API](https://api.typo3.org/9.5/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_resource_1_1_file_reference.html)

Comment: There wont be more than the 5 cases described. Thats why i think switch/case is more clear. Can you tell me how to acces for exmaple the second element in {files} is it possible without an iterator inside my switch/case? Something like {files}[2].originalFile.

Comment: that cannot be guaranteed. what about the solution I added?

Comment: I tried to add your code but i am getting an error message. Is there no need for f:then after each if condition? 
"PHP Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File could not be converted to string in "

Comment: you can ommit the `f:then`-Tag if there is no `f:else`. for your error message: I think you need to change the content of the `item` section. build a clean link and give a clean size(?) value which gets linked.

Comment: and another version of the `item`section

Comment: Thank you for helping: Now i get this error: "Fluid parse error in template Standard_action_Textmedia_b1f2c912fa4ebb3a9b15de742cb249f7d6d4231a, line 63 at character 18. Error: Templating tags not properly nested. Expected: TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Link\TypolinkViewHelper; Actual: TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\ViewHelpers\ThenViewHelper (error code 1224485398). Template source chunk: </f:then>"

Comment: i think i forget to change: "{file.publicUrl}" in the item section, i'll check that tomorrow and report to you

One more question:
youre code says: <f:if condition="{files->f:count()} == 3"></div></f:if> 
Can you explain what is it used for?

Comment: just in case of exact 3 files the inserted opening and closing `div`-Tags are not balanced: only 1 file is handled separate, and there are no other odd numbers because everything else is cut off after 4

Comment: still got the error from 16 hours ago and dont know how to solve it

Comment: Solved it for now, but i think youre solution with section would be better.